# Force iOS to not use AGPS

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

Is there a way to force iOS devices to not use the AGPS but only the normal sattelite GPS with the Titanium.Geolocation method?

Answer (score 2):

You can't access real GPS even with native iOS itself. The only thing you can do is setting [accuracy](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation-property-accuracy) to BEST as on native iOS programming. In addition to that you can use the compass feature, as described [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Geolocation). You may also have a look at the native [implementation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html).

Comment: How would i use the heading/compass in this case? Along with my location listener or replace the location listener with the heading listener?

Comment: I've tried something different too; I've added a mapview to my view and set the pinpoint everytime the location handler gets a location. This makes my script update WAAYYYY more often and giving exact locations instead of AGPS 'jumpy' locations. When i don't update the pinpoints but show the map. It works until i put my iphone on standby. Can you explain this perhaps?

Comment: ios doesn't allow background processing usually. You can change this in Info.plist (also possible via titanium) and say that your app tracks location. then your app will run in background. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/

Comment: It's running in the background. I've changed the info.plist. It still doesn't explain how my GPS goes from VERY good with pin updating to VERY poor when not pin updating(In standby mode in both cases that is. I save the coords in a database that's how i know it jumps)

Comment: difficult to say without implementation details

Comment: That's my issue exactly. Titanium has no source to see into their framework. So i can't figure out what the pinpointing is doing to my script. Nonetheless thanks for the answer

Comment: titanium is available via github. you can look into the code their. https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/tree/master/iphone